# CSS Screen Style

Tags: css, gwt

By using GWT UiBinder how to fix an image at the bottom of the screen? and how to fix an image at the center of the screen? please anyone of you help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
#imageatbottomofscreen{
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
}
#imageincenterofscreen{
position:absolute;
top:50%;//may not need
left:50%;//these two lines
height:400px;
width:1000px;
margin-left:-500px;//half of width
margin-top:-200px;//half of height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using UIBinder I image that you're using a Layout Widget. In that case I would modify the code to use a [DockLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) or some of the VerticalPanel or HorizontalPanel playing with the align property.

Take a look to the official documentation: [DevGuideUIPanels](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html)